# How splitting in spring integration works for web container?

Tags: multithreading, http, split, spring-integration, web-container

I want to use Spring Integration for HTTP inbound message processing.

I know, that it spring integration channel would run on a container thread, but if I want to use splits, 
what threads would be used?

How the result of split would be returned to the initial web request thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: *I am not 100% sure if I understand you use case, but as a general remark:*)

The [spring integration spitter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/splitter.html) splits a message in multiple "smaller" messages. This is unrelated to multi-threading, that is, it does not per-se imply that the smaller messages are processed in parallel. It is still a sequential stream of smaller messages.

You can then process the smaller messages in parallel, by defining a handler with a given parallelism and you can define that this handler uses a dedicated thread pool.

(Sorry if this does not answer your question, please clarify).

Comment: I think, you got it right. For instance, I've splitted the messages to the smaller ones. Then I want to process each of them in parallel (like parsing the message and sending the HTTP request to external web service) . I create channel with executor with fixed thread pool and forward the messages there. Would the initial thread wait for them? How I would get the result?

Comment: Yes, this is how I see it. And all the messages coming from the different container threads will be processed in the fixed thread pool. The container threads are there to keep the HTTP responsive; the fixed thread pool will work on the messages; the queue in-between acts like a buffer.

Comment: And once all thread pool threads will be done with the messages, the processing would back to the container thread? Should I define this behavior somehow explicitly?

Comment: If you want to suspend the web container thread; you will need to use a messaging gaeway and aggregate the results and return them to the gateway. The gateway can be configured with a timeout.